# How to integrate latest updated Google Cloud messaging in android project using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I am integrating the latest updated Google Cloud Messaging library, but when running I am always getting regId null, with the error "Error :SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE".

I have added google play services in the project, and also defined meta tag. Can you help me?

Comment: Is it an Android project? Can you quote your code?

Comment: would it be possible that your testing device / emulator does not have any internet connection or that you have forgotten to set the internet and GCM permissions in your manifest file?

Comment: i have added GCM permissions and internet connection is also available in testing device. i am also getting regid null .

Comment: Have you try the get started demo [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)? And [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) is the instruction.